# Will OpenCV Python - Structural Similarity Index Measure Method have the 32bit Python Support

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-image, 32-bit, ssim

I am working on the Image Processing and comparison. The Goal is to achieve the difference between Reference and Actual Image. Looks OpenCV Python SSIM Method would be good, need help whether the SSIM Method shall be achieved with 32bit python Libraries.

Looks like, the libraries which used in the SSIM Method ,(scikit-image , skimage) doesnot have the support of 32bit python. Anyone used 32bit python libraries for the SSIM Method.